# Python Nested Dictionaries Retrieve Key from nested value

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, recursion

I have a Python dictionary with dictionaries nested heavily within. There are several tiers.

What I am trying to accomplish is a function where I can enter any one of the "subcategories" values, for example, 20003482 or 200000879 and it has to return the first nested subcategory key, so for the above examples, 100003109

I am unsure about the best way to go about this, but I've tried something like

```
        group = [k for k, v in category_groups.items() if c1 in v][0]
```

and that only seems to work for the first tier of nesting

is there a general recursive solution here? whats the best way to go about this

```
cat_list = {
  1: {
    'name': 'Clothing & Accessories',
    'subcategories': {
      100003109: {
        'name': "Women's Clothing",
        'image': '/images/vectors/niche/womens.jpg',
        'description': 'Womens Dresses, Blouses, Hoodies, Sweaters, Jackets, Leggings & Much More',
        'winning': True,
        'subcategories': {
          200003482: {
            'winning': False,
            'name': 'Dresses',
            'subcategories': {}
          },
          200001648: {
            'winning': False,
            'name': 'Blouses & Shirts',
            'subcategories': {}
          },
          100003141: {
            'winning': False,
            'name': 'Hoodies & Sweatshirts',
            'subcategories': {}
          },
          200000783: {
            'name': 'Sweaters',
            'winning': True,
            'subcategories': {
              200000879: {
                'name': 'Pullovers'
              },
              200000877: {
                'name': 'Cardigans'
              },
              200000882: {
                'name': 'Vests'
              },
              200000881: {
                'name': 'Shrugs'
              },
              200217993: {
                'name': 'Cloak'
              }
            }
          },
        }
      },
      100003070: {
        'name': "Men's Clothing",
        'image': '/images/vectors/niche/mens.jpg',
        'description': 'Mens Hoodies, T-Shirts, Jackets, Jeans, Suits & Much More',
        'winning': False,
        'subcategories': {
          100003084: {
            'winning': True,
            'name': 'Hoodies & Sweatshirts',
            'subcategories': {}
          },
          200000707: {
            'name': 'Tops & T-Shirts',
            'winning': False,
            'subcategories': {
              200000717: {
                'name': 'Tank Tops'
              },
              200010062: {
                'name': 'Polo Shirts'
              },
              100003071: {
                'name': 'T-Shirts'
              }
            }
          },
        }
      },
  },
  2: {
    'name': 'Electronics',
    'subcategories': {
      509: {
        'name': 'Phones',
        'image': '/images/vectors/niche/mobile.jpg',
        'description': 'iPhone & Android Accessories, Cases, Chargers',
        'winning': False,
        'subcategories': {
          200084017: {
            'winning': False,
            'name': 'Mobile Phone Accessories',
            'subcategories': {
              200003189: {
                'name': 'Mobile Phone Lenses'
              },
              200003130: {
                'name': 'Armbands'
              },
              200003132: {
                'name': 'Power Bank'
              },
              200003089: {
                'name': 'Phone Screen Protectors'
              },
              200217751: {
                'name': 'Wireless Chargers'
              },
              200217746: {
                'name': 'Car Chargers'
              },
              100003569: {
                'name': 'Mobile Phone Cables'
              },
              100003571: {
                'name': 'Mobile Phone Chargers'
              },
              5093005: {
                'name': 'Mobile Phone Straps'
              },
              5093004: {
                'name': 'Mobile Phone Holders & Stands'
              },
              5093006: {
                'name': 'Mobile Phone Adapters'
              },
              5093001: {
                'name': 'Mobile Phone Stickers'
              }
            }
          },
          200216959: {
            'winning': False,
            'name': 'Phone Bags & Cases',
            'subcategories': {
              200215191: {
                'name': 'Battery Charger Cases'
              },
              200216972: {
                'name': 'Wallet Cases'
              },
              200216991: {
                'name': 'Phone Bumper Cases'
              },
              200216981: {
                'name': 'Fitted Cases'
              },
              200216980: {
                'name': 'Phone Pouches'
              },
              200216978: {
                'name': 'Rhinestone Cases'
              },
              200216977: {
                'name': 'Flip Cases'
              },
              200217991: {
                'name': 'Slim Cases'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      7: {
        'name': 'Computers',
        'image': '/images/vectors/niche/computer.jpg',
        'description': 'Tablet & Office Gadgets, 3D Printing Pens, Computer Peripherals & Cleaners. Laptop Accessories.',
        'winning': False,
        'subcategories': {
          200004720: {
            'winning': True,
            'name': 'Office Electronics',
            'subcategories': {
              2107: {
                'name': 'Projectors'
              },
              200138005: {
                'name': '3D Pens'
              },
              200042003: {
                'name': '3D Printers'
              },
              200140003: {
                'name': '3D Printing Materials'
              }
            }
          },
          200002361: {
            'winning': False,
            'name': 'Tablet Accessories',
            'subcategories': {
              200002368: {
                'name': 'Tablet Touch Pens'
              },
              200002365: {
                'name': 'Tablet Stickers'
              },
              200002364: {
                'name': 'Tablet Cases'
              },
              200002624: {
                'name': 'Tablet Stands'
              },
              200003724: {
                'name': 'Tablet Screen Protectors'
              }
            }
          },
          200002342: {
            'winning': False,
            'name': 'Computer Peripherals',
            'subcategories': {
              708024: {
                'name': 'Keyboard & Mouse Sets'
              },
              708023: {
                'name': 'Mouse Pads'
              },
              708032: {
                'name': 'USB Docks & Hubs'
              },
              70802: {
                'name': 'Keyboards'
              },
              70805: {
                'name': 'Mice'
              },
              7171: {
                'name': 'USB Gadgets'
              }
            }
          },
          708022: {
            'winning': False,
            'name': 'Computer Cleaners',
            'subcategories': {}
          },
          100005063: {
            'winning': True,
            'name': 'Laptop Accessories',
            'subcategories': {
              200002360: {
                'name': 'Laptop Desks'
              },
              721: {
                'name': 'Laptop Cooling Pads'
              },
              380110: {
                'name': 'Laptop Bags & Cases'
              },
              708031: {
                'name': 'Laptop Skins & Stickers'
              },
              708021: {
                'name': 'Keyboard Covers'
              },
              200216761: {
                'name': 'Laptop Stand'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      44: {
        'name': 'Gadgets',
        'image': '/images/vectors/niche/electronics.jpg',
        'description': 'Camera Accessories & Lighting, Selfie Sticks, Earphones & Headphones, Smart Watches, E-Cigs & Vapes, Gaming Accessories, Speakers & Solar Gadgets',
        'winning': False,
        'subcategories': {
          200002395: {
            'winning': True,
            'name': 'Camera & Photo',
            'subcategories': {
              200002411: {
                'name': 'Photographic Lighting'
              },
              200002408: {
                'name': 'Tripod & Accessories'
              },
              200002413: {
                'name': 'Mini Camcorders'
              },
              200216548: {
                'name': 'Tabletop Shooting'
              },
              1901: {
                'name': 'Film Camera'
              },
              1903: {
                'name': 'Camera & Photo Accessories'
              },
              200216669: {
                'name': 'Selfie Sticks'
              },
              200216611: {
                'name': 'Flashes & Accessories'
              }
            }
          },
          200002398: {
            'winning': True,
            'name': 'Portable Audio & Video',
            'subcategories': {
              200003109: {
                'name': 'Earphone Accessories'
              },
              200217778: {
                'name': 'Translator'
              },
              63705: {
                'name': 'Earphones & Headphones'
              },
              63708: {
                'name': 'Microphones'
              }
            }
          },
          200010196: {
            'winning': True,
            'name': 'Smart Electronics',
            'subcategories': {
              200086023: {
                'name': 'Smart Home Electronics'
              },
              200010206: {
                'name': 'Smart Watches'
              }
            }
          },
          200002394: {
            'winning': False,
            'name': 'Accessories & Parts',
            'subcategories': {
              200084029: {
                'name': 'Smart Power Sockets & Plugs'
              },
              200003200: {
                'name': 'Tech Cables & Accessories'
              },
              200003127: {
                'name': 'Cable Winders & Protectors'
              },
              380210: {
                'name': 'Camera/Video Bags'
              }
            }
          },
          200005280: {
            'winning': False,
            'name': 'Electronic Cigarettes & Vapes',
            'subcategories': {
              200005289: {
                'name': 'Electronic Cigarette Mods'
              },
              200005288: {
                'name': 'Elctronic Cigarette Chargers'
              },
              200005282: {
                'name': 'Electronic Cigarette Accessories'
              },
              200005281: {
                'name': 'Electronic Cigarette Kits'
              },
              200005287: {
                'name': 'Electronic Cigarette Batteries'
              },
              200005285: {
                'name': 'Electronic Cigarette Atomizers'
              },
              200005284: {
                'name': 'Eletronic Cigarette Atomizer Cores'
              }
            }
          },
          200002396: {
            'winning': False,
            'name': 'Video Games',
            'subcategories': {
              200215241: {
                'name': 'Stands'
              },
              200215236: {
                'name': 'Screen Protectors'
              },
              200215208: {
                'name': 'Joysticks'
              },
              200215202: {
                'name': 'Cases'
              },
              200215201: {
                'name': 'Bags'
              },
              200215228: {
                'name': 'Handheld Game Players'
              },
              200215227: {
                'name': 'Gamepads'
              },
              200215197: {
                'name': 'Chargers'
              },
              200004542: {
                'name': 'Video Games Wheels'
              }
            }
          },
          200216623: {
            'winning': True,
            'name': 'Earphones & Headphones',
            'subcategories': {
              200216686: {
                'name': 'Earphones'
              },
              200216605: {
                'name': 'Headphone/Headset'
              },
              200216593: {
                'name': 'Bluetooth Earphones & Headphones'
              }
            }
          },
          200084019: {
            'winning': True,
            'name': 'Wearable Devices',
            'subcategories': {
              200010211: {
                'name': 'Smart Accessories'
              },
              200010209: {
                'name': 'Smart Activity Trackers'
              },
              200010207: {
                'name': 'Smart Wristbands'
              },
              200010206: {
                'name': 'Smart Watches'
              }
            }
          },
          200215272: {
            'winning': False,
            'name': 'VR/AR Devices',
            'subcategories': {
              100007533: {
                'name': '3D Glasses/ Virtual Reality Glasses'
              }
            }
          },
          200216592: {
            'winning': False,
            'name': '360° Video Cameras & Accessories',
            'subcategories': {
              200215271: {
                'name': '360° Video Camera'
              }
            }
          },
          200217534: {
            'winning': False,
            'name': 'Speakers',
            'subcategories': {
              518: {
                'name': 'Portable Speakers'
              },
              200217564: {
                'name': 'Subwoofer'
              },
              200217561: {
                'name': 'Soundbar'
              }
            }
          },
          200218547: {
            'winning': False,
            'name': 'Solar Gadgets',
            'subcategories': {
              200218548: {
                'name': 'Solar'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  }
}
```

In terms of examples, here is what should happen:

Entering 10003109, 200003482 or 200000879 should result in the value of the key 10003109.

Entering 100003070, 100003084 or 200000717 should result in the value of the key 100003070

Entering 509, 200084017 or 200215241 should result in the value of the key 509

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines? you may want to refactor it and test it with multiple cases, I only tried the cases you mentioned but it should be enough to put you on the right track

```
def get_subcategory_high_level(cat_list, subcategory_id):
    for k, category in cat_list.items():
        first_key = get_subcategory(category, subcategory_id)
        if first_key:
            return first_key


def get_subcategory(cat_list, subcategory_id):
    if "subcategories" in cat_list:
        for k, v in cat_list['subcategories'].items():
            if subcategory_id == k:
                return k
            else:
                match = get_subcategory(v, subcategory_id)
                if match:
                    return k
```

Comment: This only returns the first category, for example, there are multiple subcategories within 1:, as in womens clothing, mens clothing etc

Comment: I thought that this is what you were looking for `and it has to return the first nested subcategory key`. Which category id are you looking for then?

Comment: what I mean by first, is first tier, so for example, the first "NESTED" list of subcategories, after 1 : {

so like anything in the first "subcategories" category if that makes sense

Comment: I did a small change, try now. It may still not do exactly what you want though, if it is the case a couple of clarifying examples would help

Comment: I have modified it. Please carefully take a look at the new dictionary and the examples provided. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I see, thanks for the examples, much clearer now, I changed the answer. I think that the key with value 2 is in the wrong position (should probably be with the keys at the highest level of cat_list). Anyway, the answer should do it, small tweaks may be needed but I am sure you will be able to pick it up from here

Comment: thanks for the answer. is it possible to create a helper function with this, that would create list of dictionaries containing and showing the nested categories and their names, for example, if you were in category 200000879, pullovers, then `[{1: 'Clothing& Accessories'}, {100003109: 'Womens Clothing'}, {200000783: 'Sweaters'}, {200000879: 'Pullovers'}] `

just so I can create a convincing navigation

Comment: sure, you can do it in many different ways. You can define a list variable at high enough scope and append objects to it while recursing (which is probably the worst solution with the one requiring less changes with a recursive approach). You can move from a recursive to a non recursive solution, using something like a pointer and then simply use a list defined in the same scope. Or you can create a data structure to wrap the json/dictionary in a tree and then have methods to show the navigation... it is really up to how much time you have to spend on that

Comment: The "Maintain state" section should give you an idea of how to use a list in the global scope and use the recursive approach
https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 different solutions.  The simpler one would be here you know that the subcategories are at a fixed depth, in this case

```
cat_list[n]['subcategories'][upper_item]['subcategories'][lower_item]
```

This can be solved with nested loops. I would write it using `for` loops and once working, convert to list comprehension.

The second more complicated way is arbitrary levels, using recursion.  should not be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
def get_key(nested_dictionary, thing):
    for key, value in nested_dictionary.items():
        if type(value) is dict:
            if key == thing:
                print(value)
            get_key(value, thing)
        else:
            if key == thing:
                print(value)
```

Where you can just return the function at the prints or you could append them to a list etc. If you need clarification on how it works you can just comment and I will answer : )